# Facebook customer chat plugin implementation with Tag Manager error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-tag-manager, facebook-messenger

**Working solution**

Found the answer on [this article by Simoa Hava](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/add-facebook-messenger-chat-google-tag-manager/)

**Problem**

We have implemented the Facebook customer chat using GTM. While version 2.11 worked fine, v2.12 doesn't work as it doesn't allow me to add the code below

[Implementation guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin)

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  page_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  theme_color="#921710"
  logged_in_greeting="Hi! Got any questions? Ask us anything, or get stuck in for more inspiration!"
  logged_out_greeting="Hi! Got any questions? Ask us anything, or get stuck in for more inspiration!">
</div>
```

The error I get is

> Invalid HTML, CSS or JavaScript found in template.

Previous working code:

```
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.11'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  jQuery('body').append('<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="xxxxxxxxxx" minimized="false"> </div>');

    </script>
```

**Updated code with jQuery - Still shows error**

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
jQuery('body').append('<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="xxxxxxxxxxx" theme_color="#921710" logged_in_greeting="Hi! Got any questions? Ask us anything, or get stuck in for more inspiration!" logged_out_greeting="Hi! Got any questions? Ask us anything, or get stuck in for more inspiration!"  minimized="true"></div>');
```

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: So what was the code for v2.11 that still worked?

Comment: @CBroe can't seem to be able to format the code to add it here as a comment.

Comment: Please put that in the question, that’s unreadable in comments.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, done it now. thanks

Comment: That second code snippet only loads and initializes the SDK, the chat plugin is not getting initialized anywhere in there.

Comment: @CBroe you are correct, I forgot to add the jQuery part in the code above. The old code doesn't have any div tags, could that be the reason of the error for the new version?

Comment: Which way are you trying to embed this through GTM? Should be a “Custom HTML tag” type I suppose.

Comment: Yup that's what I am using. It doesn't like the "your customer chat code" part it seems as if I just add the script then it saves fine.

Comment: I think this might be due to the non-standard attributes used there - if you remove anything but the class attribute from that div, is it still complaining? (Of course it won’t work any more then, try it just for debugging purposes.)

Comment: Yup, the below gets saved without any errors alongside the rest of the code

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat">
</div>

Comment: Any advice on how I can change the code so it saves without any errors?

Comment: Well if creating the element using jQuery worked before, I don’t see why it wouldn’t still ... so create try and create the element that same way, but add the additional attributes `theme_color`, `logged_in_greeting` and `logged_out_greeting`.

Comment: @CBroe I amended the code to use jQuery, but I still get the error :/ I have added the code above. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Do I need to put the  `<div id="fb-root"></div>` part into a jQuery as well?

Comment: I managed to get it working using this solution:
 https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/add-facebook-messenger-chat-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Thanks for the help @CBroe